# Calculus - relative extrema

Tags: calculus

The Legon SRC is organising a heritage trip to some regions in Ghana as part of the nation’s 60th
anniversary celebrations. the student body decides to contract Antrak Air, an airline company 
based in Accra, to convey them to and from their various destinations. The plane has a total 
capacity of 155 seats which includes the pilot, his co-pilot and three cabin crew members. Antrak 
Air decides to charge GHS 480 per student and in addition a surcharge of GHS 60 for any unsold 
seat. 
a. Write down a mathematical equation showing the airline’s total revenue
b. How many seats must be left unused to maximize the airline’s revenue
c. What price will each student pay to meet the airline’s maximum revenue
d. As a financial analyst, would you advise the SRC to pursue this deal with the airline, assuming 
that they want to charge 600 per trip. What will be your recommendation to the SRC?

Comment: 1) What have you tried? and 2) I'm always perplexed when a calculus teacher gives an optimization problem with discrete data.

Comment: Man I've tried and still not getting the concept .. Too difficult to break it down

Comment: Try this:  Suppose 10 students go on the trip.  What will the airline charge? In that case, what will each student have to pay?  Now suppose 25 students go on the trip.  Answer the same questions.  Now suppose $x$ students go on the trip.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2177830/18398

Comment: Guys I still need help with this question.